# How to download a big file from google drive via curl in Bash?

Tags: bash, curl, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I wanna make a very simple bash script for downloading files from google drive via `Drive API`, so in this case there is a big file on google drive and I installed `OAuth 2.0 Playground` on my google drive account, then in the `Select the Scope` box, I choose `Drive API v3`, and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` to make a token and link.

After clicking `Authorize APIs` and then `Exchange authorization code for tokens`. I copied the `Access token`like below.

```
#! /bin/bash

read -p 'Enter your id : ' id
read -p 'Enter your new token : ' token
read -p 'Enter your file name : ' file

curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$id?alt=media" -o "$file"
```

but it won't work, any idea ?

for example the size of my file is 12G, when I run the code I will get this as output and after a second it back to prompt again ! I checked it in two computers with two different ip addresses.(I also add `alt=media` to URL)

```
-bash-3.2# bash mycode.sh

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   166  100   166    0     0     80      0  0:00:02  0:00:02 --:--:--    80

-bash-3.2#
```

the content of file that it created is like this

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "downloadQuotaExceeded",
    "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The download quota for this file has been exceeded."
 }
}
```

Comment: Out of scope for the question, but in case it's useful - I've found it pretty easy move stuff into/out of Google Drive on the CLI using [rclone](https://rclone.org/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to download a file from Google Drive using the curl command with the access token.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modified curl command:

Please add the query parameter of `alt=media`.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$id?alt=media" -o "$file"
```

#### Note:

- This modified curl command supposes that your access token can be used for downloading the file.
- In this modification, the files except for Google Docs can be downloaded. If you want to download the Google Docs, please use the Files: export method of Drive API. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: thnx for your answer but unfortunately it won't work either !

Comment: @Freeman Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the error message and/or response message? And also, can I ask you about the result of difference between the curl command of your question and the modified curl command?

Comment: @Freeman Thank you for replying. Can you also add the curl command for replicating your current issue? I would like to test it in my environment.

Comment: @Freeman And also, when the issue in your additional information occurs, when the file is created, can you show the file content? Because in your situation, I thought that the error message might be included in the file. But I'm not sure whether this leads to the direct solution. I have to apologize for this.

Comment: @Freeman Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. 1. Can I ask you about the difference of results between the curl command of your question and the modified curl command? 2. Can you also add the current curl command for replicating your current issue?

Comment: I put in in my question both are the same and in the file says `The download quota for this file has been exceeded.`

Comment: @Freeman Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your replying. Can you explain about the detail of it?

Comment: sure you told me what is the different between two output, 1)with `alt=media` and 2)without `alt=media` and as I told the output was same, also in the content of file that it created was `The download quota for this file has been exceeded.`

Comment: @Freeman Thank you for replying. `downloadQuotaExceeded` means that in the current stage, the file cannot be downloaded. So it is required to wait for 1 or several days. But now, I would like to confirm about your situation. So I proposed to provide the current curl command and the error message. By this, I thought that it can know whether the command can download the file from Google Drive before you wait for the days. From your replying, I would like to propose to wait for a day or days, and test it again. At that time, please add `alt=media`.

Comment: @Freeman Or, as another test case, how about creating a small file and testing to download it? In this case, I think that you can test it now. How about this?

Comment: sure, but how about these files ? imagine I have several files and I need to work with them so every time I have to wait ?

Comment: @Freeman  I think that it might due to many accesses in the short time for testing. So I think that when the curl command for downloading can be completely used, the file can be smoothly download. But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So about this, it's my guess. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Freeman As the additional information, when the test for downloading a small sample file worked fine using the modified curl command using `alt=media` with the access token, the large file can be also downloaded. About this, also in my environment, I could confirm.

Comment: Is the **$token** value in `Bearer $token` the same as an API key generated from Google?  Also, where do I get **$id** in the path argument `"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$id?alt=media"`?  @Tanaike Were you ever able to download a large file using this approach?

Comment: @siralbert About your 1st question of `Is the $token value in Bearer $token the same as an API key generated from Google?`, it's no. About your 2nd question of `Also, where do I get $id in the path argument "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/$id?alt=media"? @Tanaike Were you ever able to download a large file using this approach?`, I cannot understand it. So, can you post it as a new question? If you can cooperate to resolve your 2nd question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Tanaike Done.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947814/how-can-i-download-a-file-over-the-maximum-file-size-limit-from-google-drive-pro

Answer (score 3):

## UPDATE AS FOR MARCH 2021

Simply follow this guide [here](https://medium.com/@acpanjan/download-google-drive-files-using-wget-3c2c025a8b99). It worked for me.

#### In summary:

For small files to download run

`wget --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O FILENAME`

While if you are trying to download a quite large file you should try to run

`wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILEID' -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=FILEID" -O FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt`

Simply substitute **FILEID** and **FILENAME** with your custom values.

**FILEID** can be found in your file share link (after the /d/ as illustrated in the article mantioned above).

**FILENAME** is simply the name you want to save the download as. Remember to include the right extension. For Example `FILENAME = my_file.pdf` if the file is a pdf.

Comment: I am trying to download a large file from Google Drive, but the **wget** command isn't working for me.

Comment: I checked the size and it only downloaded about 2400 bytes out of the 89 MB from the file and I am unable to extract the contents of the file.  I am able to get the entire contents of the file directly from the file link in my browser after clicking through the **Can't scan the file for viruses** prompt.

Comment: Opened a new question.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77947814/how-can-i-download-a-file-over-the-maximum-file-size-limit-from-google-drive-pro

Answer (score 0):

**This is a known bug**

It has been reported in this Issue Tracker [post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149891169). This is caused because as you can read in the documentation:

*(about download url)*

> Short lived download URL for the file. This field is only populated
>   for files with content stored in Google Drive; it is not populated for
>   Google Docs or shortcut files.

So you should use another field.

---

> You can follow the report by clicking on the star next to the issue
>   number to give more priority to the bug and to receive updates.

---

As you can read in the comments of the report, the **current workaround** is:

- Use webContentlink instead

or

- Change `www.googleapis.com` to `content.googleapis.com`

Comment: thnx for your reply but my files are on google drive, so I don't have any choice.