# How can I download a file over the maximum file size limit from Google Drive programmatically?

Tags: bash, http, cookies, google-drive-api

I have a large file (*supplier-data.tar.gz*) that I wanted to download programmatically from Google Drive by using the following commands on the linux shell.

```
wget --load-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=$(wget --quiet --save-cookies /tmp/cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies --no-check-certificate "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=$FILEID" -O- | sed -rn 's/.*confirm=([0-9A-Za-z_]+).*/\1\n/p')&id=$FILEID" -O $FILENAME && rm -rf /tmp/cookies.txt
```

I tested this on a smaller file and it works.  I checked that I allowed anyone to access the files that I was testing this on and that I used the correct $FILEID from the share link.  I executed the above snippet while logged in on my own system.

The problem is when I change the $FILEID and the $FILENAME to a large file (for example, *supplier-data.tar.gz*) on Google Drive, the resulting download isn't the same file stored on Google Drive.  I know that if you download a large file using the Google Drive website, a prompt pops up and requires user intervention as shown in the attached screenshot.

Another screenshot with the log messages produced from the command snippet is attached.[image: Can't scan file for viruses][image: log messages]

Comment: work for me -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928444/how-to-download-large-tgz-file-from-google-drive-for-installing-docker-containe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Installed gdown `pip install gdown`
2. Then, ran `gdown <file-id>` to download large file from Google Drive.

Thanks to pgame 001. See [How to download large .tgz file from Google drive for installing Docker containers on Cloud9 Ubuntu 18.04LTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75928444/how-to-download-large-tgz-file-from-google-drive-for-installing-docker-containe)